# How to perform a map reduce in MongoDB with a colon in the field name?

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce, field

In MongoDB I have fields with a colon in the name.
To address a field I would normally use:

```
var map = function() {
              emit(this._id, this.sth.field);
}
```

but with a colon inside the field name like:

```
var map = function() {
               emit(this._id, this.sth.fie:ld);
}
```

MongoDB returns `JavaScript execution failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected token :`

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Property names in JavaScript can be quoted or unquoted.

When the property name results in invalid JavaScript syntax, you need to switch to the quoted technique: `this.sth['fie:ld']`.

```
var map = function() {
    emit(this._id, this.sth['fie:ld']);
}
```